# Why enumerate items in a table make spacing around them?

Tags: tables, enumerate, enumitem

I have trouble with `enumerate` items in tables.
Please take a look below.

Although I've used to the `enumitem` package to eliminate all spaces around `enumerate` items, they make spacing when in a table.

How can I fix this?

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{
    itemsep=0pt,
    topsep=0pt,
    parsep=0pt,
}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tabular}{ | p{1\linewidth} |}
        \hline
        General paragraph\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}

    \vspace{40pt}

    \begin{tabular}{ | p{1\linewidth} |}
        \hline
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item {} 
            Enumerate item
        \end{enumerate}\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Additional space vertical space before and after list is defined by `\topsep` and `partopsep`. This space you can reduce or eliminate as it is suggested in received answers.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend defining a new `enumerate`-like list for using in `tabular` and related environments. With the help of `before`  and `after` you can remove the additional space around the item:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{
    itemsep=0pt,
    topsep=0pt,
    parsep=0pt,
}

\newlist{tabenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[tabenum]{wide=0pt, 
                  nosep, 
                  leftmargin= * ,
                  label*=\arabic*.,
                  after=\vspace{-\baselineskip},
                  before=\vspace{-0.6\baselineskip}}


\begin{document}

    \begin{tabular}{ | p{1\linewidth} |}
        \hline
        General paragraph\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}

    \vspace{40pt}

    \begin{tabular}{ | p{1\linewidth} |}
        \hline
        \begin{tabenum}
            \item Enumerate item
        \end{tabenum}\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

A variant with `etoolbox`  and a `\compress` command borrowed from an answer on this site.

Additionally, the width you chose for the `p{..}` column does not take into account the inter column spacing  nor the vertical rules width, hence an overflow into into the right margin, as you can see from the first table:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand{\ShowFrameLinethickness}{0.3pt}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{array}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}

\AtBeginEnvironment{tabular}{\setlist[enumerate]{label=(\arabic*), nosep, leftmargin =*, after=\vspace{-\baselineskip}}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\compress}{\@minipagetrue}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

        \noindent
    \begin{tabular}{ | p{1\linewidth} |}
        \hline
        General paragraph\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}

    \vspace{40pt}
    \noindent
    \begin{tabular}{ |>{\compress\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr1\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth} |}
        \hline
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item Enumerate item
            \item Another enumerate item
        \end{enumerate}\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]